# IP forwading amazon ec2 another server IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, nat, cloud

I use this command in windows azure (NAT), to redirect all requests to another server with other IP

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 10.240.154.15 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.188.47.63
```

¿ can do this with amazon ec2 ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿ can do this with amazon ec2 ?

Si.

You'll just need to make sure that source/destination checks are disabled for that EC2 instace.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me more, ¿what would be the option in the VPC console amazon?